# 'Add XY Data' and 'Make XY Event Layer' are plotting points at an inaccurate latitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, latitude-longitude, xy

I have a .csv file with 10 wells and their respective longitude (X) and latitude (Y). Every time I try 'Add XY Data' or 'Make XY Event Layer', my wells are being plotted at some random place in the world and not on our job site. So to see what was going on, I added two new columns to the attribute table and used field calculator to calculate the longitude and latitude of wherever these wells are plotted. They are plotting at the correct longitude, but the latitude for each well is plotting at 0.000369. I can't understand what is going on. I have done these exact steps hundreds of times and have never had this issue.[image]

Comment: Please post the details of all the parameters/values that you used in the X/Y tool/dialogue, including the X field, Y field and spatial reference system values.

Comment: Longitude is my X, Latitude is my Y, everything is projected to NAD83 UTM Zone 18N

Comment: UTM doesn’t use latitude/longitude.  Are you sure that’s the right coordinate system?